# Using ConcurrentHashMap for parallelism

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, hashmap

I've a program where I am trying to understand thread parallelism. This program deals with coin-flips and counts the number of heads and tails (and the total number of coin flips).

Please see the following code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class CoinFlip{


    // main
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2){
            System.out.println("CoinFlip #threads #iterations");
            return;
        }

        // check if arguments are integers
        int numberOfThreads = 0;
        long iterations = 0;

        try{
            numberOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            iterations = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("error: I asked for numbers mate.");
            System.out.println("error: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // ------------------------------
        // set time field
        // ------------------------------


        // create a hashmap
        ConcurrentHashMap <String, Long> universalMap = new ConcurrentHashMap <String, Long> ();

        // store count for heads, tails and iterations
        universalMap.put("HEADS", new Long(0));
        universalMap.put("TAILS", new Long(0));
        universalMap.put("ITERATIONS", new Long(0));

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Thread[] doFlip = new Thread[numberOfThreads];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i ++){
            doFlip[i] = new Thread( new DoFlip(iterations/numberOfThreads, universalMap));
            doFlip[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
            try{
                doFlip[i].join();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        // log time taken to accomplish task
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println("Runtime:" + elapsedTime);

        // print the output to check if the values are legal
        // iterations = heads + tails = args[1]
        System.out.println(
            universalMap.get("HEADS") + " " +
            universalMap.get("TAILS") + " " +
            universalMap.get("ITERATIONS") + "."
        );

        return;
    }



    private static class DoFlip implements Runnable{

        // local counters for heads/tails/count
        long heads = 0, tails = 0, iterations = 0;
        Random randomHT = new Random();

        // constructor values -----------------------
        long times = 0; // number of iterations
        ConcurrentHashMap <String, Long> map; // pointer to hash map

        DoFlip(long times, ConcurrentHashMap <String, Long> map){
            this.times = times;
            this.map = map;
        }

        public void run(){
            while(this.times > 0){
                int r = randomHT.nextInt(2); // 0 and 1

                if (r == 1){
                    this.heads ++;
                }else{
                    this.tails ++;
                }
                // System.out.println("Happening...");
                this.iterations ++;
                this.times --;
            }

            updateStats();
        }


        public void updateStats(){
            // read from hashmap and get the existing values
            Long nHeads = (Long)this.map.get("HEADS");
            Long nTails = (Long)this.map.get("TAILS");
            Long nIterations = (Long)this.map.get("ITERATIONS");

            // update values
            nHeads = nHeads + this.heads;
            nTails = nTails + this.tails;
            nIterations = nIterations + this.iterations;

            // push updated values to hashmap
            this.map.put("HEADS", nHeads);
            this.map.put("TAILS", nTails);
            this.map.put("ITERATIONS", nIterations);

        }
    }
}
```

I am using a ConcurrentHashMap to store the different counts. Apparently, when the returns wrong values.

I wrote a PERL script to check the (sum of) values of heads and tails (individually for each thread), it seems to be appropriate. I cannot understand why I get different values from the hashmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A concurrent hash map provides you with guarantees with respect to visibility of changes with respect to ***the map*** itself, not to its values. In this case you retrieve some values from the map, hold them for some arbitrary amount of time, then try and store them into the map again. In between the read and consequent write though, ***any number of operations might have happened on the map***.

The concurrent in concurrent hash map just guarantees, for example, that if I put a value into a map, that I will actually be able to read that value in another thread (aka it will be visible).

What you need to do is ensure that all threads accessing the map *wait their turn*, so to speak, when updating the shared counters. In order to do this, you either have to use an atomic operation like 'addAndGet` on AtomicInteger:

```
this.map.get("HEADS").addAndGet(this.heads);
```

or you need to synchronize both the read and write manually (most easily accomplished by synchronizing on the map itself):

```
synchronized(this.map) {
    Long currentHeads = this.map.get("HEADS");
    this.map.put("HEADS", Long.valueOf(currentHeads.longValue() + this.heads);
}
```

Personally, I prefer to leverage the SDK whenever I can, so I would go with the use of an Atomic data type.

Comment: Thanks very much. I understood the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

You should use AtomicLongs as values and you should create them only once and increment them instead of get/put.

```
 ConcurrentHashMap <String, AtomicLong> universalMap = new ConcurrentHashMap <String, AtomicLong> ();
 ...
 universalMap.put("HEADS", new AtomicLong(0));
 universalMap.put("TAILS", new AtomicLong(0));
 universalMap.put("ITERATIONS", new AtomicLong(0));
 ...
 public void updateStats(){
        // read from hashmap and get the existing values
        this.map.get("HEADS").getAndAdd(heads);
        this.map.get("TAILS").getAndAdd(tails);
        this.map.get("ITERATIONS").getAndAdd(iterations);
 }
```

Long is immutable.

An example:

```
Thread 1: get 0
Thread 2: get 0
Thread 2: put 10
Thread 3: get 10
Thread 3: put 15
Thread 1: put 5
```

Now your map contains 5 instead of 20

Basically your problem is not the Map. You can use a regular HashMap since you do not modify it. Of course you have to make the `map` field `final`.

Comment: That is one appropriate solution; but still I would like to understand how this code is potentially wrong OR giving me undesired outputs.

Comment: OK I see what you are saying.

So I should access the universalMap in every iteration (and that to 3 times?). So if I have 10 million coin flips, I would be accessing my HashMap almost 30 Million times? I don't think that's efficient.

Comment: No, see the example above.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things.  One you really don't need to use a ConcurrentHashMap.  A ConcurrentHashMap is only useful when you are dealing with concurrent put/removes.  In this case the map is fairly static as far as the keys go simply use an UnmodifiableMap to prove this.

Finally if you are dealing with concurrent adds you really should consider using a [LongAdder](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LongAdder.java?name=v13.0-rc2&r=06cbdb1ed84f235b51fec6acc740d8261357545d).  It scales far better when many parallel adds occur in which you don't need to worry about the count until the end.

```
public class HeadsTails{
    private final Map<String, LongAdder> map;
    public HeadsTails(){
       Map<String,LongAdder> local = new HashMap<String,LongAdder>();
       local.put("HEADS", new LongAdder());
       local.put("TAILS", new LongAdder());
       local.put("ITERATIONS", new LongAdder());
       map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(local);
    }
    public void count(){
        map.get("HEADS").increment();
        map.get("TAILS").increment();
    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(map.get("HEADS").sum());
         /// etc...
    }
}
```

I mean, in reality I wouldn't even use a map...

```
public class HeadsTails{
    private final LongAdder heads = new LongAdder();
    private final LongAdder tails = new LongAdder();
    private final LongAdder iterations = new LongAdder();
    private final Map<String, LongAdder> map;
    public void count(){
        heads.increment();
        tails.increment();
    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(iterations.sum());
    }
}
```